# Сортировка диапазонов ip адресов

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Есть список ip адресов, например:

> `109.111.104.0 - 109.111.111.255
> 109.111.112.0 - 109.111.119.255
> 109.111.96.0 - 109.111.103.255
> 109.111.96.0 - 109.111.127.255`

В данном случае набор диапазонов был отсортирован как строки. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как наиболее эффективно отсортировать очень большой набор таких диапазонов учитывая числовые значения, т.е. получиться должен такой набор:

> `109.111.96.0 - 109.111.103.255
> 109.111.96.0 - 109.111.127.255
> 109.111.104.0 - 109.111.111.255
> 109.111.112.0 - 109.111.119.255`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Моя реализация на питоне:

```
from socket import inet_aton, inet_ntoa
import sys

def list_ips():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        ip1, ip2 = line.split('-')
        yield inet_aton(ip1.strip()), inet_aton(ip2.strip())

for ip1, ip2 in sorted(list_ips()):
    print('%s - %s' % (inet_ntoa(ip1), inet_ntoa(ip2)))
```

Алгоритм практически такой-же как и у [@avp](/users/232/avp). Для проверки взял [отсюда](http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ip_ranges/get_ranges.php) адреса USA и перемешал их:

```
$ wc US_ipranges.txt 
 26071  78216 806100 US_ipranges.txt
$ shuf US_ipranges.txt > US_ipranges_shuf.txt
$ time python test.py < US_ipranges_shuf.txt > /dev/null

real    0m0.177s
user    0m0.160s
sys     0m0.014s
```

Comment: Хороший язык питон. Никак не возьмусь освоить его.

Answer (score 4):

Преобразуете IP из строк в двоичный формат (inet_addr() сетевой порядок байт), затем  в порядок байт хоста  и поместите в струтуру, описывающую диапазон. Отсортируйте массив этих структур, потом можно быстро искать двоичным поиском.

Чтобы поиск нормально работал, преобразование из сети в хост (функция ntohl()) **необходимо**.

Короче, примерно так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

#define N 1000

struct ips {
  unsigned int ip1, ip2; // 32 bit
};

static int
cmp (const void *a1, const void *a2)
{
  struct ips *p1 = (struct ips *)a1, *p2 = (struct ips *)a2;
  if (p1->ip1 < p2->ip1)
    return -1;
  else if (p1->ip1 > p2->ip1)
    return 1;
  if (p1->ip2 < p2->ip2)
    return -1;
  else if (p1->ip2 > p2->ip2)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n;
  if ((n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]):N) <= 0)
    n = N;

  struct ips ipd[n];
  char strip1[20], strip2[20], dummy[20];

  int i = 0, j;
  while (i < n && scanf("%s %s %s",strip1,dummy,strip2) == 3) {
    ipd[i].ip1 = ntohl((unsigned int)inet_addr(strip1));
    ipd[i].ip2 = ntohl((unsigned int)inet_addr(strip2));
    i++;
  }
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf ("%x - %x\n",ipd[j].ip1,ipd[j].ip2);

  qsort (ipd,i,sizeof(ipd[0]),cmp);

  // your main part
  printf ("-----\n");
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf ("%x - %x\n",ipd[j].ip1,ipd[j].ip2);
}
```

Comment: Объясните Ваше мнение более развернуто. Что именно не эффективно.

Comment: Читаемость низкая, это да, а работать будет в разы быстрее, чем строки подогнанные под лексикографическую сортировку.

Comment: Вот есть серьезные сомнения по поводу "быстрее".
Функция inet_addr переводит ip адрес в int из разных систем счисления, выполняются дополнительные проверки и циклы. Перекодирование будет довольно длительным. 
Сортировка конечно будет работать быстрее, и то есть сомнения, но в ассемблере не силен точно сказать не смогу сколько там тактов будет при 24байтных строках...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, допускаю, что будет выигрыш производительности при N проходов для дополнения лидирующими нулями, но но его съест N log N строковых сравнений.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, автор говорит:

     "очень большой набор". 

Поэтому работа с памятью будет жрать много ресурсов (считаем, что *очень большой*, это когда массив диапазонов не влезает в кэш CPU). Разница между числами и строками получается в 6 раз. 

Кстати, проверок и циклов для дополнения нулями Вам все равно не избежать.

Самом собой время построения и сортировки вообще-то для практики не важны, важно будет время поиска в рабочем цикле.

--

А Вы программку-то напишите, времена померьте.

Comment: Вот мне самому интересно. Не спорю, что строки сравниваются медленнее, чем int. Вопрос в inet_addr, какова его эффективность, с учетом кучи условий и циклов? 
Кроме того, строки сравниваются побайтно? - имхо, зависит от процессора, может и по 4 байта за раз...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, строки будут сравниваться, как Вы напишите. В случае str[n]cmp() побайтно.

IMHO inet_addr() от предполагаемой процедуры "нормализации" строкового IP будет отличаться максимум 12-ю умножениями и сложениями.

Еще раз говорю, для практической задачи временем **построения конфигурации** можно пренебречь. В любом случае (если она в ОЗУ помещается) это займет меньше минуты. Любая структура разумного размера для подобной задачи будет сделана меньше чем за секунду.

Если Вам **все** тонкости **реально** интересны, то качните исходники (например из GNU) и посмотрите.

Comment: посмотрел функцию в исходниках, сравнил со своим подходом. у меня сильно хуже, да. согласен, так быстрее, чем с каким-либо строками. а еще быстрее получится? Если в int64 запихать оба адреса?

Comment: По идее, да будет быстрее. 

--


Вместо struct взять union { unsigned long long k; struct ips { ... } ips; }; и поменять функцию cmp(). Возможно (не соображу, проверять надо) порядок ip1, ip2 в ips для x86 тоже надо менять. Это все не очень хорошо - машинозависимо (можно ifdef-ами, но морока).

Еще сортировку поменять, взять **хороший** quicksort и вставить его по месту в стиле C template.

Только программа (исходник) разрастется неимоверно. 

--

Вот на питоне @Ilya Pirogov меня порадовал. И ведь быстро - 26000 диапазонов за 0.17 сек.